# Java 8 Streams & lambdas maintaining strict FP

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

Java 8 lambdas are very useful in many situations to implement code in a FP fashion in a compact  way.
    But there are situations where we may have to access/mutate external state which is not a good practice as per FP practices.
(because Java 8 Functional interfaces have strict input and output signatures we can't pass extra arguments)

Eg:

```
class Country{
        List<State> states;
    }
    class State{
        BigInt population;
        String capital;
    }

    class Main{
        List<Country> countries;

        //code to fill
    }
```

**Let's say the use case is to get list of all capitals and and the whole population of all states in all countries**

Normal Implmentation:

```
List<String> capitals = new ArrayList<>();
BigInt population = new BigInt(0);

for(Country country:countries){
    for(State state:states){
        capitals.add(state.capital);
        population.add(state.population)
    }
}
```

How to implement the same with Java 8 Streams in a more optimized manner?

```
Stream<State> statesStream = countries.stream().flatMap(country->country.getStates());

    capitals = statesStream.get().collect(toList());
    population = statesStream.get().reduce((pop1,pop2) -> return pop1+pop2);
```

But the above Implementation is not very efficient.Any **other better way to manipulate more than one collection using Java 8 Streams**

Comment: You code is not “not very efficient”, your code does not work at all. There is no `get()` method on `Stream` and streams do not magically select the right property for you.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to collect multiple results in one pipeline you should create a result container and a custom `Collector`.

```
class MyResult {
  private BigInteger population = BigInteger.ZERO;
  private List<String> capitals = new ArrayList<>();

  public void accumulate(State state) {
    population = population.add(state.population);
    capitals.add(state.capital);
  }

  public MyResult merge(MyResult other) {
    population = population.add(other.population);
    capitals.addAll(other.capitals);
    return this;
  }
}
MyResult result = countries.stream()
  .flatMap(c -> c.getStates().stream())
  .collect(Collector.of(MyResult::new, MyResult::accumulate, MyResult::merge));

BigInteger population = result.population;
List<String> capitals = result.capitals;
```

Or stream twice, as you did.

Comment: But before you waste time implementing such a `Collector`, you should verify the initial claim about the efficiency. Iterating over a list isn’t expensive while doing two entirely different things at once may hinder the JIT’s optimization potential…

Comment: I think efficiency in this context means not streaming twice. Since this operations won't take long.

Comment: Yes, but what does “streaming twice” mean? It just means iterating over the source lists which the OP claims to be “not very efficient” without further reference. In terms of development expense, two stream statements are far simpler than this collector and in terms of execution speed, as said, no clear statement possible, but no reason to assume that a two-in-one collector will outperform streaming-twice significantly.

Comment: I totally agree. IMO OP's question was _Any other/better way to manipulate more than one collection using Java 8 Streams_.

Comment: IMO streaming twice is much more obscure in terms of intent, particularly when you want to do filter operations and have to apply the filter in two pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can only consume a stream once, so you need to create an aggregate that can be reduced:

```
public class CapitalsAndPopulation {
  private List<String> capitals;
  private BigInt population;

  // constructors and getters omitted for conciseness

  public CapitalsAndPopulation merge(CapitalsAndPopulation other) {
    return new CapitalsAndPopulation(
      Lists.concat(this.capitals, other.capitals),
      this.population + other.population);
  }
}
```

Then you produce the pipeline:

```
countries.stream()
  .flatMap(country->
    country.getStates()
      .stream())
  .map(state -> new CapitalsAndPopulation(Collections.singletonList(state.getCapital()), state.population))
  .reduce(CapitalsAndPopulation::merge);
```

The reason this looks so ugly is that you don't have nice syntax for structures like tuples or maps, so you need to create classes to make the pipelines look nice...

Comment: Where is constructor?

Comment: I've omitted it for conciseness. I've edited my answer to make it more obvious.

Comment: @kewne you made the point, there are no easy ways to create a separate structure on the fly

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
class Pair<T, U> {
    T first;
    U second;

    Pair(T first, U second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}

Pair<List<String>, BigInteger> result = countries.stream()
    .flatMap(country -> country.states.stream())
    .collect(() -> new Pair<>(
            new ArrayList<>(),
            BigInteger.ZERO
        ),
        (acc, state) -> {
            acc.first.add(state.capital);
            acc.second = acc.second.add(state.population);
        },
        (a, b) -> {
            a.first.addAll(b.first);
            a.second = a.second.add(b.second);
        });
```

You can use `AbstractMap.Entry<K, V>` instead of `Pair<T, U>`.

```
Entry<List<String>, BigInteger> result = countries.stream()
    .flatMap(country -> country.states.stream())
    .collect(() -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
            new ArrayList<>(),
            BigInteger.ZERO
        ),
        (acc, state) -> {
            acc.getKey().add(state.capital);
            acc.setValue(acc.getValue().add(state.population));
        },
        (a, b) -> {
            a.getKey().addAll(b.getKey());
            a.setValue(a.getValue().add(b.getValue()));
        });
```